# Why class variables behave different than methods in inheritance?

Tags: java, inheritance

```
public class AbcMain {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Parent p = new Child();
    p.sayHello();
    System.out.println(p.a);
}
}

class Parent{
int a = 10;
public void sayHello(){
    System.out.println("Hello inside parent.");
}
}

class Child extends Parent{
int a = 20;
public void sayHello(){
    System.out.println("Hello inside child. ");
}
}
```

Output is : Hello inside child. 10

Confused here, It is calling the method of Child() as the instance is of child. Then why it prints a = 10?

Comment: use getter method to get value of a => `int getA()` , Then override method in `Child` vlass

Answer (score 2):

In java method overriding is there. No `variable` overriding.

Just for testing change the variable name in parent to `parentA`  and see  :)

Answer (score 1):

Your `Parent p`is `Child` type. Now `p` is a `Child` instance. So now you are invoking `Child`
s properties. And `Child` will override  `Parent` `sayHello` method.

You should learn about Java [polymorphism](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html) and [inheritance](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html).

Answer (score 1):

There is no "overriding" of fields in Java as there is with methods. So you could think that since `Child` overrode `satHello` only one instance of the method exists (for the perspective of other classes). However, with fields both instances exist. Therefore `Parent.a = 10` and `Child.a = 20`. Since p is declared as `Parent` you got 10.

Comment: Can you pinpoint this behavior in the JLS? I tried to look it up but failed.

Comment: I think the section on "shadowing" might be it: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.4.1

Answer (score 0):

Since the object type is `Parent`, `p` will have all the characteristics of an `Parent`. But, since the object created is a `Child`, any overridden methods in the `Child` class will be used instead of those in the `Parent` class. That's why you got `Hello inside child` as first output.

As, `Child` is a subclass of `Parent`, First, `Child` default constructor will be invoked, and so `a` is initialized to `20`, then there will be a call to `Parent` default constructor and the value in variable `a` becomes `10` and thus you will get the second output as `10`(The first line in your `Child` constructor would be `super()` by default unless you call an overloaded constructor of `Child` using `this()`).